# Are "x == a || b" and "x == a || x == b" equivalent statements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How are these statements equivalent?

var test = 'one'

```
if( test == 'car' || 'one' ){
console.log('spo')
}
```

And

```
if( test == 'car' || test == 'one' ){
console.log('spo')
}
```

Comment: no they arent equivalent, if you are testing the contents of that variable you'll want to use the latter.

Comment: For something that invoked so much discussion AND CONFUSION seems it was a fair question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent.

```
if( test == 'car' || 'one' ){
    console.log('spo')
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if( test == 'car' || 'one' != ''){
  console.log('spo')
}
```

Comment: A more accurate equivalent would be `test == 'car' || Boolean('one')` since `||` is interested in a ToBoolean evaluation. Not a coercing equality evaluation.

Comment: @graystateiscoming No, the second operand is just returned. So if `test` is not `'car'`, `'one'` will be returned, not `true`.

Comment: @graystateiscoming But that throws extra stuff into the mix. I say it is the same as `(text == 'car') || 'one'`: it still evaluates to a value which will be used by the conditional. Then it's a matter of saying which values are "true" separately.

Comment: @lonesomeday: I just meant with respect to the true/false evaluation, it isn't a coercing equality evaluation, but rather a boolean evaluation. But since it is the last operand, you're right in that it does skip the evaluation altogether. When it isn't the last operand, it gets the value, does a ToBoolean, then returns the value if a truthy result was found.

Comment: and actually, since we're in an `if()` condition, the `if()` does consider whatever it is given to as a ToBoolean, so ultimately whatever value is returned will get the ToBoolean treatment.

Comment: @graystateiscoming True enough.

Comment: @gray state is coming: you're right, just fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

No. The first test will always pass.

If the left hand side of the `||` is falsey, it will return the right hand side. The right hand side (`'one'`) will therefore be returned. This is truthy, so the test will pass.

Answer (score 1):

No. They are not.

In the first conditional, `test == 'car' || 'one'` *is the same as* `(test == 'car') || 'one'` which *always* evaluates to a [truthy-value](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/) (namely, the result of the equality *or* "one").

The latter conditional only yields true when test is "car" or "one", and false in all other cases.

Try it with *failing* test values as well, like "hello" for a counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

Um, no. A language like Javascript with accept 'one' as been true. So the first test will always pass. 
The second one has the capability of being false since we have no idea what test could be.

Comment: I don't think javascript is crazy at all, it is doing what any other programming language does with the result of an expression / boolean-it's up to the programmer to handle the control flow carefully.

Comment: xD I just like thinking of Javascript as being crazy. You can feed it anything and it will almost always run.

Comment: In a "sane" language like C# || 'one' would never compile :P 
Hope that clears it up.

Comment: You can't compare C# with javascript, and the result is similiar if you take numbers in an if condition in C++ and C#.

Comment: Touche, I will remove "crazy" if it makes you happy :)